# Changing src attributes of images

Tags: jquery, dom, slimbox

I'm trying to avoid having to create duplicate images (one thumbnail one full size) with my usage of slimbox.

I have the 'thumbnail' image scaled to 100% width and height 'auto' so they all fit nicely in their parent container, scaled to thumbnail size. Clicking opens the full size image in a lightbox. That part is good to go.

What i would like to improve upon is the actual relationship between the two images. Currently I have

```
<a href="path/to/image.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="some title">
<img src="path/to/image.jpg">
```

Since they are using the same image, I would like to programmatically populate the

```
<a href="XXX">
```

with the same path as the image source. I think i can use sibling selector ".next" to do this and add a class to the  itself.

```
$(function(){
    $('a.foo').each(function() {
        $(this).next('img').attr('href', this.href);
    });
});
```

obviously that isn't working, syntax is incorrect. Can anyone suggest a good way to do this?
thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right side and there is no syntax error in your code, but images have no `href` attributes, you should modify their `src` attributes, Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.foo').each(function() {
        $(this).next().attr('src', this.href);
    });
});
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $('a.foo').each(function() {
      var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      $(this).attr('href', src)  
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PzYQt/1/)

Comment: Sorry for the idiocy in my post. Yes, images have no href, I was meaning source as you pointed out. This looks like it should work, but when I try it the "href" of the <a> is missing it is simply "href" no "href="something""

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Do you wanna change the `href` attributes of anchors based on the `src` attributes of images or vice versa?

Comment: Again my apologies. I want to 'populate' the anchor href value with the image src attribute.

Comment: @undefined - you should use `.parent()` instead of `.prev()`

Comment: @ahren Its not clear from the markup, if anchor tag is the parent of the image, you are correct, as he have used `next` I thought that they are siblings.

Comment: Man. This should be easy! Here's a fiddle so you can more clearly see what Im trying to do, grab the anchor href from the img src attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/PzYQt/

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Yes, you should use `find()` method. try this http://jsfiddle.net/PzYQt/1/

Comment: @undefined and ahren, thank you both. works perfect! I was missing/unaware of the .find method. Thank you very much.